# dialog position with offset doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Need help positioning a dialog that I'd like to open in the same spot relative to the viewport itself, not some element on the page.

I have it opening in the top right of the browser window but I had thought I could use "offset" to move it down a bit. Offset seems to do nothing and it continues to stick to the upper right corner of the browser window.  Reading the documentation is not much help.

Here's my script:

```
jQuery("#dialog-profile-more").dialog( { 
autoOpen: false,
dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
height: "auto",
width: 300,
position: { my: "right top", 
            at: "right top", 
            of: window, 
            offset: "25 25"  }
} );
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited to add, the position of the dialog should be fixed in that if you scroll down the page, the window stays in the upper right corner. Perhaps I need to use css for the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was the answer: css styling and adding position fixed and some margin to my dialogWithDropShadow class. Thanks everyone....